# Standard Keyboard Layouts

Tags: unicode, localization, keyboard, standards, keyboard-layout

I'm working on a FOSS project at http://unicode.codeplex.com.  In this project we try to collect some information about standard keyboardlayouts.

What we want to know is there a place or document or ... which mention what's the Standard Keyboard Layout for exact language.

I mean if you are a German or American or Arab or ... , what's the standard keyboard layout in your country?

As you know there are too many layouts for each country but (in most countries) the Standard Organization of each country provide a standard layout for keyboard and all of the people should use it to prevent characters inelegance.

So if you know a document or just know your country (or some countries) standard keyboard layout please complete these information, or what else you think may help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
      <Standard xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
             <Item Country="Iran" KeyboardLayout="ISIRI 9147" StandardDate="2004/09" License="Gratis" Producer="ISIRI" ProjectURL="http://sourceforge.net/projects/farsitools/" Referer="Nasser Hajloo" RefererMail="n.hajloo@gmail.com" />
      </Standard>
```

Each Item provided for each country and here is the attribute description

1. **Country** = Country name
2. **KeyboardLayout** = the name of standard keyboard layout
3. **standarddate** = when this layout was standarded
4. **License** = what's the keyboard layout license. if you do not know leave it blank
5. **Producer** = the name of standard organization
6. **projectURL** = if the project is available on the web and is published by the producer, where is it? if you do not know leave it blank
7. **Referer** = Your Full Name
8. **RefererMail** = Your email

Comment: Use "Open Source" phrase instead of "FOSS", It's better known/

Comment: The basic layout of keyboards tends to be similar in a given country, but there are often small differences, particularly in the peripheral keys.  For example, the keyboard I'm using has 78 keys; many a US keyboard has 104 with a separate numeric key pad (conspicuously absent on this machine).  Nevertheless, it is similar to most other US keyboards - though it has keys that are not found on PC keyboards.

Comment: Dear Jonathan, as you mentioned in most of countries the layout of keyboard hs small changes and most of users use differeent keyboards (with or without periferal keys) but foreach countries like France, Norway , K.S.A , Israel, Japan, China, or vice versa, the keyboards have serios unicode issue, the standard organization force the hardware companies to create standad keyboard (with number of kys) and they also provide a standard laout that show the exact character t use ( for example ي is a arabi char and ی is a persian char ) they are similarbut have serios different.

Comment: Arabian users have to use ي and persian users have to use ی. so there shouldbe a standard for these users that solve this problems. these issues mostly resolved by a standard keybaord layout but users do not know whats the standard keyboard and they confused , most of them use from the provided OS layout without knowing that is it standard or not, for example default persian keyboard layout of windosw is not standard and it causes a wide variety of inelegance

Comment: anybody do not know any standard keyboard ?

Comment: check on open source operation systems. they have support for different keyboard layout for each country. Maybe there you can find about the (licence, dates, layout) for each country.